# Apache Cordova on WP8: Don't reload on returning to app

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have a cordova app that displays our mobile website in an iframe. When I hit the Windows Button and open the app again, it's reloaded and the last seen context is lost. How do I save the context for the next time the app is opened again?

Answer (score 0):

What I was experiencing is the default behaviour of Windows Phone. The back button brings you to the "page" (= state) of the app that you just left but touching the tile will open a new instance.

Changing this means activating a concept called "Fast App Resume". This answer was very helpful for me to implement that correctly:
This is basically an awkwardly asked version of 
[Fast App Resume issues in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352171/fast-app-resume-issues-in-windows-phone-8)